# Native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, snappy

I got the above error when I was using MLUtils saveAsLibSVMFile. tried various approaches like below but nothing worked.

```html
  /*
   conf.set("spark.io.compression.codec","org.apache.spark.io.LZFCompressionCodec")
  */

  /*
  conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath","/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/snappy-java-*.jar")
  conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath","/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/snappy-java-*.jar")
  
    conf.set("spark.executor.extraLibraryPath","/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop/lib/native")
    conf.set("spark.driver.extraLibraryPath","/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop/lib/native")
  */
```

I read the following links https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/18903/this-version-of-libhadoop-was-built-without-snappy.html

Finally there were only two ways I could solve it. This is given in answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One approach was to use a different hadoop codec like below 
   `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "true")
       sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type", CompressionType.BLOCK.toString)
       sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec")
       sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress", "true")
       sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec")`
2. Second approach was to mention --driver-library-path `/usr/hdp/<whatever is your current version>/hadoop/lib/native/` as a parameter to my spark-submit job (in command line)